# If $L^*$ is the formal self-adjoint of and $n$th order differential operator $L$ show that the formal adjoint of $L^*$ is $L$.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $L^*$ is the formal self-adjoint of and $n$th order differential operator $L$ show that the formal adjoint of $L^*$ is $L$.

*Proof*

By definition and hypothesis $L^* = L$. Therefore $\left(L^* \right)^* = \left(L\right)^* = L.$

Is it that easy or do I have to do some integration?

Comment: I'd say you are correct, but you should appeal to the construction of the formal adjoint, perhaps in terms of indefinite integrals, where you integrate by parts to move all derivatives of $f$ in $\int (Lf)gdx$ to $g$.